# python TypeError: '>; not suppported between instances of 'str' and NoneType

Tags: python-3.x

This is the output I need
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2

The example they start you off with is wrong you must use try/except and while true for the grader to accept.  I am having trouble with finding the min and max this is the code I have wrote it is similar to the code they start you off with. They say to have a continue in there but I have no idea where to put it.

I've tried a bunch of combinations as well as tried to go off the answers on this site.

```py
    largest_so_far = None
    smallest_so_far = None
    while True:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if num == 'done' :
            break
        try:
            int(num)
        except:
            print('Invalid input')
    for the_num in [num]:
        if num > largest_so_far:
            largest_so_far = the_num

    for the_num2 in [num]:
        if num > smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = the_num2
            #continue
    print('Maximum', the_num)
    print('Minimum', the_num2)
```

I want the output of 
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2

However I get the error

```
TypeError: '>; not suppported between instances of 'str' and NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `so_far` variables are initialized to `None`, and are compared to some number before assigning new values to them; as the error says, you can't use `>` to compare a number and `None`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

1. You aren't populating any list with the numbers entered from the user. Initialize an empty list, and add the valid inputs to the list as the user enters them. If you want the user to be able to type 'done', don't immediately turn it into an integer. You perform that check a few lines later in your try/except block.

```py
user_inputs = [] # Store numbers in here
while True:
    num = input('Enter a number: ')
    if num == 'done' :
        break
    try:
        user_inputs.append(int(num)) # Add it to the list if it is an int.
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
```

2. Move the initialization of your largest and smallest to after the while loop and instead of setting it to None, set it to the first element in the list (but make sure there are elements in the list first). Since you originally initialized them to `None`, the first comparison you perform will try to check if an integer is greater than or less than `None` which doesn't make sense. In this case, it's valid to initialize them to the first element of your input list.

```py
if len(user_inputs) != 0:
    largest_so_far = user_inputs[0]
    smallest_so_far = user_inputs[0]
else:
    print("You didn't enter any numbers!")
    largest_so_far = None
    smallest_so_far = None
```

3. There is no need to loop over the same list twice. You can do both checks in one loop. Perform a for-each loop over each element in `user_inputs`. Fix the comparison in where you check for the smallest element. You should use the `<` operator instead of the `>` operator.

```py
for element in user_inputs:
    if element > largest_so_far:
        largest_so_far = element
    if element < smallest_so_far:
        smallest_so_far = element
```

4. In your code, `the_num` and `the_num2` will be the last element of your list and not the smallest/largest values, which is what your objective was. Instead, print out the smallest and largest values.

```py
print("Maximum:", largest_so_far)
print("Minimum:", smallest_so_far)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 12
Enter a number: 51
Enter a number: -2
Enter a number: 3.4
Invalid input
Enter a number: test
Invalid input
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: done
Maximum: 51
Minimum: -2
```

Comment: Thank you.  We haven't learned anything about append yet and I still dont understand why just having user_inputs = [] works but it does thank you very much